# play.api.libs.json is not able to parse uuid string

Tags: scala, playframework

In scala play application, I am trying to parse uuid as a json response but getting error:

```scala
play.api.libs.json.Json.parse(s"""
{
  "id" : "ac435876-fe73-4385-a9dd-af54ce2d7a7d"
}
""")
```

> Error- play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'C': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false') at [Source: (String)"

Comment: What you posted works fine. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/610B7Zm7QoOeVxsUThDtYw

Comment: Are you sure about the json you're getting from the client? The error clearly indicates that there's JSON syntax error while parsing http request, and also, the same code works on scastie, as @Dylan mentioned.